# PHPExcel identify a .xlsx file as a CSV file

Tags: php, excel

My PHP version is 5.2.9. And I use `PHPExcel 1.7.5` to parse a file of Excel2007. But with the same source code and the same Excel file, it came into different results on two machine. The two machine were with the same PHP and PHPExcel deployment. One worked well and the other parsed all Excel2007 file as CSV file.

I debugged the two case and finally found the differences as follow.

```
public function canRead($pFilename)
{
    // Check if zip class exists
    if (!class_exists('ZipArchive')) {
        return false;
    }

    // Check if file exists
    if (!file_exists($pFilename)) {
        throw new Exception("Could not open " . $pFilename . " for reading! File does not exist.");
    }

    $xl = false;
    // Load file
    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    if ($zip->open($pFilename) === true) {
        // check if it is an OOXML archive
        $rels = simplexml_load_string($this->_getFromZipArchive($zip, "_rels/.rels"));
        foreach ($rels->Relationship as $rel) {
            switch ($rel["Type"]) {
                case "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument":
                    if (basename($rel["Target"]) == 'workbook.xml') {
                        $xl = true;
                    }
                    break;

            }
        }
        $zip->close();
    }

    return $xl;
}

...

public function _getFromZipArchive(ZipArchive $archive, $fileName = '')
{
    // Root-relative paths
    if (strpos($fileName, '//') !== false)
    {
        $fileName = substr($fileName, strpos($fileName, '//') + 1);
    }
    $fileName = PHPExcel_Shared_File::realpath($fileName);

    // Apache POI fixes
    $contents = $archive->getFromName($fileName);
    if ($contents === false)
    {
        $contents = $archive->getFromName(substr($fileName, 1));
    }

    return $contents;
}
```

The `$contents` value printed out on the work-well machine were `xml definition tag`. But the other machine returned a `empty` string.

The `$fileName` value is `"_rels/.rels"`. I google it and found it was a relationship file. Was it compressed in the Excel2007 file? Could someone tell me more information about this file? And how to fix this parse problem?

FYI, I used few code to test this case and the problem appeared everytime. The code is as follow.

```
<?
    require_once("PHPExcel/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php");
    echo @PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify('/tmp/styleA.xlsx');
    echo "\n";
    exit();
?>
```

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: All `.xlsx` files are compressed. The file `_rels/.rels` simply links some other file properties. Specifically it points the excel file to `app.xml`, `core.xml` and `workbook.xml`. One of your installs could be corrupted. It also could have to do with the OS each system is on.

Comment: As far as solving the problem goes, you mention your code is the differences, do you mean that it is extra code on one side?

Comment: @Foo_Chow Thanks for the explanations of `_rels/.rels`. And my code in two machine are the same, included the test code above. I just used a Excel2007 file, the PHPExcel lib and the 4 lines test code. I think the problem is caused by the differences of environment variables. But I still can't find the true causes. You mention that there would be some corrupted installs. Could you limit them among some libs or other extension modules?

Comment: @Foo_Chow I work on two x86_64 GNU/Linux machines

Comment: Ok, so your issue is that PHPExcel is not reading the `_rels/.rels` file. Try replacing the following in `canRead()`: `$rels = simplexml_load_string` with `$rels = simplexml_load_string($zip->getFromName('_rels/.rels'));`. If this works the `_getFromZipArchive()` function is the issue.

Comment: @Foo_Chow I have already tested this. It came info different at `$archive->getFromName($fileName)`. Yesterday I have made it through. And I have found some difference with the environment on the two machines. I thought the issue was that the go-wrong machine do not add `--enable-zip` when install php. Although it added `zip.so` extension, it gone wrong in this case. Finally I installed php again with `--enable-zip` and it worked well. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I caught the true issue. It occured by the `php installation`.

The go-wrong machine used `php-cgi` to start service and the other used `php`. And the go-wrong machine did not add `--enalble-fastcgi` configuration though it had `zip.so` extension. If you want to use `zip` in the project, you'd better add `--enable-zip` (not `--with-zip` !!!) configuration when install php. Add php extension `zip.so` after installing php somehow it could go wrong.